# How can i share data between Main Target and UITest runner target?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcuitest

I want to share data between the Main app target and the XCUITest target. I didn't find any solution. Is dis possible?

Comment: Depend on how is yours data is presented.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to accomplish this if you have a shared container between your UITest runner and the app being tested.

See [Access App Groups container directory from test runner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57962035/access-app-groups-container-directory-from-test-runner/57979460#57979460)

Comment: Writing to/reading from the SIMULATOR_SHARED_RESOURCES_DIRECTORY works for me as of Xcode 12.3.

Comment: yes, but that won't work on a real device. Your UITest will fail because that directory does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

UI Tests are black boxed, so you cant have access to your code.

You can use @testable import in Unit Tests, so full access will be provided. When you're running UITests this is not working, because during a UITest your test class cannot access your app's code.

Please see this for reference:
[How do I access my swift classes from my UI tests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51799940/how-do-i-access-my-swift-classes-from-my-ui-tests)

Answer (score -1):

Like they already told you in the comments it depends on how is your data is presented.

But usually in your test file, you should import the main module:

```
import XCTest
@testable import <YOUR_MODULE_NAME>
```

Your module name is the name of your main Target.